# How do I update a document inside a forEach() loop?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update all documents inside a `forEach()` loop, but the update isn't occurring. I'm logging each iteration to make sure the `forEach()` is working, and it is. But, for some reason the `update()` is not working.

Here is my code:

```
myModelSchema.methods.updateMyModel = function (cb) {
var myModel = this.model('MyModel');

myModel.find({}, function (err, items) {
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log('item._id = ' + item._id);
        myModel.update(
            {
                _id: item._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    "some_array.0.some_field": item.some_field
                }
            }
        );
    })
});
};
```

As noted above, I see the `console.log()`, but the documents are not being updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you not simply setting **all documents** to to a constant value on a specific array element? You don't need to loop unless the actual "value to update" changes in each iteration. All you seem to be doing is applied with a simple singular update statement:  `myModel.update({ },{ "$set": { "some_array.0.some_field": someVariable } }, { "multi": true },(err,response) => { /* response object */ })`. At any rate there is no callback on the `.update()` so it does not execute, and you really need to control the loop execution on callback completion.

Comment: There are far better ways to "loop", but unless it's your explanation that is lacking in describing what you are actually intending to do in the "loop", then your simply don't need it. Just apply `"multi"` to update all matched, or `updateMany()` which "implies" the `"multi"` parameter in modern API's.

Answer (score 2):

As Neil Lunn pointed out, I didn't have a callback. Here is the solution:

```
myModel.find({}, function (err, items) {
    items.forEach(function (item) {
        myModel
            .update(
                {
                    _id: item._id
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        "some_array.0.some_field": item.some_field
                    }
                }
            )
            .exec()
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log('It works');
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    })
});
```

I needed to update a field in a document with the value of a field in the same document. The above code works.

Comment: It may work right now. But eventually it's going to fail and quite horribly so with "call stack exceeded". This is why you actually communicate with people who ask questions of the question you are actually asking.